# Split of data in PHP object

Tags: php

In the following code, is it possible to spilt the Object `$author` where `white space occurs` ?

```
<?php
$url="http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=laugh";
$twitter_xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

foreach ($twitter_xml->channel->item as $key) {
 $a = $key->{"author"}; 
 echo $a;
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure. `preg_split('/\s+/', $key->{"author"})` would split on any type of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
$split =  explode(' ', (string) $key->{"author"}));
```

OR

```
$split = preg_split('/\s+/', (string) $key->{"author"}));
```

To split by @ just take $split and run in loop

```
 foreach($split as $key => $value) {
    $eta = explode('@', $value);
    var_dump($eta);
 }
```

To check if string exist use strpos

```
foreach($split as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, '@') !== 0) echo 'found';
}
```

Comment: it works... Can i split `$split` further to check for `@` in string...?

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$array = explode(' ', $key->{"author"});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an explode function that can easily accomplish that. So, for example:

```
$a = $key->{"author"};
$author = explode(" ", $a);
$first_name = $author[0];
$last_name = $author[1];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you merely care to get 2 parts: email, and "friendly name" (cause people have 1 to n number of names).

```
<?php
$url="http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=laugh";
$twitter_xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($twitter_xml->channel->item as $key) {
 $a = $key->{"author"};
 preg_match("/([^ ]*) (.*)/", $a, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
 echo "\n";
}
?>
```